# How can I show this is an isomorphism? $\tau:k[[x]][y]/(f_a,g_a) \rightarrow\prod_{i=1}^ n k[[x,y]]/(f_{p_i},g_{p_i})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, algebraic-curves

I am reading a proof of Bezout theorem for algebraic curves and I encountered this morsphism that the author says is an isomorphism by the chinese remainder theorem:
$$\tau:k[[x]][y]/(f_a,g_a) \rightarrow\prod_{i=1}^
n k[[x,y]]/(f_{p_i},g_{p_i})$$

defined by $\tau(h) = (h_{p_1},\dots, h_{p_n})$, where the subindex ${p_i}$ means that if $h \in k[[x,y]]$ then $h_{p_i}(x,y)=h(x+a,y+p_i)$ and $f_{a}(x,y)=f(x+a,y)$, the same for $g_a$.
The morphism $\tau$ maps injectively from $k[[x]][y]$ to $k[[x,y]]$. However, I can't see why this is true.

More context about the question:

$k[[x,y]]$ is the ring of formal series in two variables.

The text proves a proposition about two polynomials $f$ and $g$ in $k[x,y]$ with no factors in common and all their zeros in common with first coordinate fixed as $a$ are of the form $(a,p_i)$.

I thought that I could show that the ideals $(f_{p_i},g_{p_i})$ are pairwise coprime and their intersection or product is $(f_a,g_a)$ then $$\prod_{i=1}^
n k[[x,y]]/(f_{p_i},g_{p_i})\cong k[[x,y]]/(f_a,g_a)$$ but I cant prove neither of these statements. Other thing I could do is to show that $$\prod_{i=1}^
n k[[x]][y]/(f_{p_i},g_{p_i})\cong k[[x]][y]/(f_a,g_a)$$ again using the chinese remainder theorem, but I dont see the coprimality between these ideals or that $(f_a,g_a)=\prod_{i=1}^
n(f_{p_i},g_{p_i})$ or $(f_a,g_a)=\bigcap_{i=1}^
n(f_{p_i},g_{p_i})$ as ideals.

Comment: There are a lot of problems in your question, the main one is that $x\to x+a$ isn't well defined $k[[x]]\to k[[x]]$.

Comment: I see, I don't know what my professor wanted to say when he wrote these notes about bezout's theorem. Perhaps, he only wanted to translate the second coordinate and that is well defined if we take polynomials on the second variable, i.e. if $h_{p_i}(x,y)=h(x,y+p_i)$ and $h \in k[[x]][y]$ there shouldn´t be a problem in the definition, right?